# reinstall os without an Apple ID

Tags: macbook

First of all ,I don't see any disk named Macintouch among the disks on the left bar after opening disk utility, and when I try to reinstall os it keeps asking for an apple ID which I don't have, I made one but seems like it won't work because I don't use it in the app store and that's because my country isn't even listed so I couldn't enter any payment method and so I keep being asked for my ID to be reviewed. When I turn my Mac on, it shows a Prohibition sign and I can't access it . what can I do? Is there anyway around the apple ID?

Answer (score 1):

Hold  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd>   <kbd>R</kbd>  at the chimes [you need to be connected to the internet, & not through a portal]

That will bring you to a Utilities page from where you can erase & reinstall - no Apple ID required if you set it up as a new machine. All previous data will be overwritten.

See [Apple KB - How to reinstall macOS](https://support.apple.com/HT204904) for full details.